# Most Common K length Sequences

Tags: c, algorithm

I saw this coding challenge posted somewhere on a Elixir forum and have not quite figured out how to solve it. I have generalized the problem to make it more understandable.

Given an input of a random sequence of numbers, compute the M most common K-length sequences. M and K are constants. For example, compute the 10 most common 3-number sequences from the input.

The input could be potentially very large, so the solution should scale to any size.

I know that storing the sequences in a hash table in a higher level language is potentially the simplest, most efficient solution, but I’d like to find another solution that can be done in C without any hash functions

Comment: Are the K-length sequences contiguous? If you don't want hash functions, build a list of K-tuples - sort the tuples with second to be compared if first numbers match and third to be compared if both the first and second numbers match and so on. Now run through the list and count tuples that are the same. Add that count to each K-tuple to form K+1 tuples. At the end your K-tuple list will be transformed to list of K+1 tuples. Sort the list by the count. The first M in the sorted list are the M most common K-length sequences.

Comment: what is the allowable range of sequence members?  single digits? 64 bit ints? floats? For small ranges, you could just maintain an occurrence table.

Comment: @SomeDude what is the run time on that solution? It seems easier than what I was thinking ...

Comment: @AShelly let’s say the input is any 32 bit int.

Comment: @SomeDude  isn’t the memory usage on that potentially very high? If there were a lot of repeated sequences, it would use way more memory that it has to. The ideal solution would somehow recognize a sequence it’s already seen on the first pass